# How could I create single list from Parent and child node from XML using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, datamodel

I need to create single list from a xml file where there is some value from Parent and Some from Child node using Linq, Then i need bind this list in a single list view in UI

```
<item>
  <name>AAA</name>
  <id>94926DD03DB67FE30B456E50A0C34DF6</id>
  <files>
    <update>1533861455395</update>
    <file>
      <name>1532997455395.pdf</name>
      <update>1532997455395</update>
    </file>
    <file>
      <name>1533861455395.pdf</name>
      <update>1533861455395</update>
    </file>
  </files>
</item>
<item>
  <name>BBB</name>
  <id>A16779822115170AECAD570D0139E8F3</id>
  <files>
    <file>
      <name>1530405455395.pdf</name>
      <update>1530405455395</update>
    </file>
  </files>
</item>
```

Code i've written where FileName showing properly but in Update value not returning

```
public void xml()
    {
        XDocument loadedData = XDocument.Load(xmlUrl);
        var lstBooks = loadedData.Descendants("item").Select(x =>
                        new
                        {
                            FileName = x.Element("name").Value,
                            Update = x.Elements("files").Select(y => y.Element("update").Value),

                        }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please give the output structure you want? Right now it is not much clear from the information you gave

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want (a list of objects containing filename and update value):

```
var lstBooks = loadedData.Descendants("file").Select(x =>
    new {
         FileName = x.Element("name").Value,
         Update = x.Element("update").Value
        }).ToList();
```

In case you want the item name and a list of updates, then use this:

```
var lstBooks = loadedData.Descendants("item").Select(x =>
    new {
         FileName = x.Element("name").Value,
         Update = x.Elements("files").Select(y => y.Element("update").Value).ToList(),
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: I want second one but still its returning {System.Collections.Generic.List<string>} }

Comment: Well off course. Your first item `AAA` contains two files. How do you want to distinguish which one you want? Your XML structure is very weird, since it has lost of duplicate element names in different parts of your tree. That's why is's very confusing to tell, which element you want!

Comment: I think the error is because you dont have an "update" xml tag directly within the files tag on the second element. It might be easier if you use more distinct xml field names

Comment: I need first one only

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a flat datatable and fill in all columns like code below :

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("Item Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Item ID", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Files Update", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("File Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("File Update", typeof(string));

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);

            foreach (XElement item in doc.Descendants("item"))
            {
                string name = (string)item.Element("name");
                string itemID = (string)item.Element("id");

                foreach (XElement files in item.Elements("files"))
                {
                    string filesUpdate = (string)files.Element("update");

                    foreach (XElement file in files.Elements("file"))
                    {
                        string filename = (string)file.Element("name");
                        string fileUpdate = (string)file.Element("update");

                        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { name, itemID, filesUpdate, filename, fileUpdate });
                    }
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```